# "miss you" vs "missing you" in the present

Tags: phrases

Both the simple and the continuous are out there, but if you had to pick one:

> I miss you.
>
> I am missing you.

...

> She misses her family.
>
> She is missing her family.

I want to say that the *stative form of this verb in the simple tense is INHERENTLY CONTINUOUS and that the continuous tense can be done without. (Should be done without for a cleaner language usage?)

Edit #2 (I meant to say stative every time I wrote *intransitive)

and I found this:

> http://is.muni.cz/th/178421/ff_m_b1/Stative_verbs_with_the_progressive.txt
>
> http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/support-files/stative-verbs-list.pdf

I thank you for the debate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your edit. Both usages are acceptable in English. You cannot just do away with one. But, you can feel free to use them fairly interchangeably.

Comment: @DavidM Thank you for your comment. Would you give me one instance where I could not get away with the simple present alone.

Comment: I believe I understand your question now. And I've answered below. In short, feel free to never use the continuous again. But, it does set a tone better in some cases as I've shown below. But, both modalities would be 100% appropriate with minimal sacrifice of meaning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh no you don't!  This guy doesn't want to know what they mean. He wants the gerund usage stricken from the language!!!!!!

Comment: @David: He's welcome to strike it from his own (personal) language - but hands off mine and yours! It's a "loaded" example though, since you'd rarely tell someone *"I'm missing you"*. On the other hand, you'd virtually *never* say to someone *"I watch  you"* - it's invariably *"I'm watching you"* (which btw isn't a "gerund usage". That's *"Does my watching while you're undressing bother you?"* - used as a *noun*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It wasn't my intention to annoy you. It's just that I noticed a pattern where *stative verbs don't need the continuous at all when in the present. I am not referring to all gerunds, as a matter of a fact I find gerund verbals some of the most interesting parts of speech. (in "I am watching you" to watch is a *dynamic verb) –

Comment: @SurvMach Whether you choose to accept it or, the continuous tense is a perfectly acceptable usage here in a few usages.  I grant you that it is not the most common usage, but in the situations I've outlined below it is correct.  Wastefulness in language is not a consideration for correctness.  Sorry.

Comment: Also, what @FumbleFingers means by a peeve is that you are expressing your dislike for a usage, not asking about the validity of that usage.  Peeves are generally considered off-topic here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, you're correct.  That was not the gerund.  I admittedly get confused on some of the proper names for grammatical devices despite my ability to use them correctly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Feel free to delete it. As I stated in my answer, this particular case seems to be evolving into both usages being completely accepted. Won't see me using the continuous in this case though.

Comment: @SurvMach: I may have higher rep than you, but I'm just a user, not a mod. So in this case, you've got more "super-powers" than me - *you* can delete *your own question*, but I can't delete it. If enough people *downvote* the question, I may be allowed to ***vote*** to delete it, but that still wouldn't happen unless several others voted to delete as well.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's all good man. I tried to delete it but it has already been answered and I can't. Please look at my answer though, my opinion is that in this particular case the language is evolving in the wrong direction. Do you consider wastefulness to be right or wrong?

Comment: @@SurvMach: I think you get better answers for stuff like this on English Language Learners - see, for example, [Is the word "think" stative or dynamic?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers friend, note that I am not questioning which verbs are stative and which are dynamic but instead the redundancy of the stative verb used in the continuous form and its implications on the sharpness of a language. #wastefulness

Comment: I think *you're assuming* English would somehow be "improved" if it discarded all constructions that might be considered "wasteful" (i.e. - if the language were "re-specified" to minimise "redundancy"). If you want that kind of thing, go for a computer language like C or Pascal. Verbal languages are more like the genetic code of DNA - what might *look* like redundancy usually turns out to be a mechanism for incorporating *flexibility to meet as-yet-unidentified needs* (or past needs which might resurface in another guise later).

Comment: @FumbleFingers deep. maybe too deep, but who am I to judge. I am thinking that I am understanding you.

Comment: I think that all native speakers would accept my usage *you're assuming* above, and that the vast majority would *approve* it over simple present in that exact context. On the other hand, few if any would accept (let alone approve) *either* of the present continuous usages in your last sentence above. But per my original closevote, the "invitation to discussion" is Off Topic and POB - and if you're not interested in *learning* why native use the forms they do, nobody is forcing you to "attend classes" at ELL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers try not to think about it every time you say it. And  yes, from a forever ESL student.

Comment: One is making the assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please paste

thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/6306002132?r=6306002132

http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/support-files/stative-verbs-list.pdf

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you want to convey a mental state or an activity.

This kind of question comes up frequently for me. I am a native English speaker, but my wife is from Germany, and I sometimes get questions like this from our German friends. (For those who do not know, German has no present progressive tense, so context and additional language must be used to convey the concept).

I don't know of a hard-and-fast rule, but I have noticed the pattern that in English, verbs denoting mental states or emotion (wants, desires, hopes, wishes...) are more often placed in the simple present, even when one might think a present progressive form would be appropriate e.g., "I love this soup." **

So although the present progressive form is perfectly acceptable, my vote would be for "I miss my family;" the implication that it is current and ongoing is already implicit in the fact that it is a mental state. (Unless of course it were part of sentence such as "I am missing my family - I just can't get a clear shot from this window." :)

Questor

** Thus I think the previous McDonalds catch phrase, "I'm loving it," is actually quite brilliant, as it turns the simple mental ascent of good taste into an enjoyable activity by the sheer act of bucking the convention.

Comment: please see question edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think this boils down to personal preference (and possibly regional dialect).

I would typically say:

I miss you.

She misses her family.

But, the others are 100% acceptable.

Of note, there is a sense of immediacy from using the gerund form. It makes it sound as if it's having an acute effect right now.

So, saying:

> I am missing my family; that's why I'm crying.

Versus:

> I miss my family.  Say, have you got any more of that delicious jam?

**Edit:** Per your request in comments. There really is not a reason you could not go the remainder of your life without using the continuous form. As I've stated, it's largely a matter of style and intent.  I would point to the examples above as a usage where the continuous is more convenient, but not critical.

Comment: the question has been edited

Comment: @SurvMach See my comment above. The edit doesn't significantly change my answer.

Comment: What do you think of this analogy? If the English language were Python code the continuous would be wasteful code. This is how I see it and that's why I dislike the usage of the continuous. I wonder if you would empathize with my perspective.

Comment: Ahhhhhh. As the child of a computer programmer, I sympathize with you. But, dislike it or not, language is something that happens around us as well as something that we make happen for our own. Your personal preference can ONLY dictate the way that you speak and write. The works of others are, unfortunately, beyond your control. So, nod and move on. Choose the usage you prefer when you speak and live and let live.

Comment: .............;)

Comment: Also, I'll add that language is far more nuanced than computer code.  It has evolved over eons to allow the description of feelings, moods, situations, eventualities, etc.  And, it often must do many at the same time. Hence the often (seemingly) redundant use cases. They often convey subtleties that computer code wouldn't need to address.

Comment: There is a great expression used by Kurt Vomnegut to describe futile efforts (in this case writing an anti-war book -- Slaughterhouse 5). It paraphrases to: Why don't you go write a book protesting trees?

Comment: Please imagine yourself on the phone with a special one... "I miss you" "I am missing you"... I can't see it, and believe me I am all for nuance.

Comment: I miss you on occasion, mostly when using the toilet for extended periods and my my mind wanders. I am missing you as we speak!  How's that for nuance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13152/discussion-between-david-m-and-survmach)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the 'sticky' 2 letter words makes a sentence more powerful and writing more persuasive/engaging. Unless you are emphasizing that her missing you is something which is occurring unexpectedly (e.g "I thought she wouldn't miss you but she *is* missing you a lot."), I'd encourage parsimony.

Comment: the question has been edited

Comment: please see question edit.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that "I miss you" is just fine, saying "I'm missing you" communicates an extra detail: that it's a temporary state--NOW--that's bound to change. So we generally say "We're missing you" when we feel really down and homesick, and we're thinking about that special person who isn't with us. So I'd say, "I'm missing you" is a touch more emphatic than "I miss you".